# How to bind two inputs in parent and child com[onents using vue3 composition API

Tags: javascript, vue.js, quasar-framework

I try to learn vue 3 with composition api and i stuck on such things. I got an parent page

```
<template>
  <q-page class="flex flex-center bg-dark row">
    <q-input
      filled
      v-model="customerModel"
      @change="setCustomer"
      dark
    />
     <RegistartionForm />
  </q-page>
</template>

<script>
import RegistartionForm from "components/RegisterComponent.vue";
import { ref } from "vue";

export default {
  components: {
    RegistartionForm,
  },
  setup() {
    const customerModel = ref("");
    return {
      customerModel,
      onSubmit() {
        console.log(customerModel.value);
      },
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

My vue component:

```
<template>
  <q-card
    class="q-pa-md sc-logon-card bg-dark col-lg-4 col-sm-12"
    align="center"
  >
    <q-input filled v-model="customerComponentModel" dark />
    <q-btn
      type="submit"
      @click="onSubmit"
    />
  </q-card>
</template>

<script>
import { ref } from "vue";
export default {
  name: "RegistartionForm",
  props: {},
  setup(props) {
    const customerComponentModel = ref("");
    return {
      customerComponentModel,
      onSubmit() {
        console.log(customerComponentModel.value);
      },
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

How can i bind customerModel and customerComponentModel inputs? Any changes in customerModel input must affect on customerComponentModel, and vice versa. Submit logic in component.
Thx for help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use v-model directive:

```
<RegistartionForm v-model="customerModel"/>
```

in child component:

```
<template>
  <input type="text" v-model="customerComponentModel" />
</template>
<script>
import { computed } from 'vue';
export default {
  props: {
    modelValue: String,
  },
  setup(props, { emit }) {
    const customerComponentModel = computed({
      get: () => props.modelValue,
      set: (value) => emit("update:modelValue", value),
    });

    return { customerComponentModel };
  },
};
```

Now the customerModel and customerComponentModel should be binded, any changes in customerModel should affect customerComponentModel and vice versa. You could read more about v-model and components [here](https://www.vuemastery.com/blog/vue-3-data-down-events-up/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<template>
  <q-page class="flex flex-center bg-dark row">
    <q-input
      filled
      v-model="customerModel"
      @change="setCustomer"
      dark
    />
     <RegistartionForm :customerModel="customerModel"/>
  </q-page>
</template>
```

`vue component`:

```js
<script>
import { computed } from "vue";
export default {
  name: "RegistartionForm",
  props: {customerModel: String},
  setup(props) {    
    const customerComponentModel = computed(() => {
      return props.customerModel
    })
    onSubmit = () => {
        console.log(customerComponentModel.value);
      }

    return {
      customerComponentModel,
      onSubmit      
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: No. Not work =( Not transfer date from customerModel to customerComponentModel. And when edit customerComponentModel log me - Write operation failed: computed value is readonly.